# Part of Speech, adverb or adjective?

Tags: meaning, parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis

From a part of *Pollyanna* written by Elenor Porter:

> "There ain't no tellin'," sobbed Nancy. "She lay back that white an'
>   still she might **easy** be dead; but Miss Polly said she wa'n't dead--an'
>   Miss Polly had oughter know, if any one would--she kept up such a
>   listenin' an' a feelin' for her heartbeats an' her breath!"

In the cited passage, what part of speech is *easy*, and what is its meaning??

Comment: I wonder why learners of English choose such dated works as *Pollyanna* to read. If you want a free text, at least F. Scott Fitzgerald is closer to our time and his English is not cryptic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an unmarked adverb.

In Standard English, it would be *easily*, but it's common in a number of dialects to turn adjectives into adverbs without using the *-ly* suffix.

Comment: For a familiar example, compare the "Turn around real slow" instead of the standard "really slowly" in pretty much any western or noir.

Comment: The use of easy as an adverb without a special ending is comparable to German where the position before an adjective shows its function of adverb. Possibly it is German influence.